# Ambiguous reference to member 'session(_:peer:didChange)' error in multipeer connectivity framework in xcode 8 swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, multipeer-connectivity

I have been working on multipeer connectivity framework.While initializing a session object ,i get an error stating "Ambiguous reference to member 'session(_:peer:didChange)' ".I get the same error while making the class as delegate of the same session object. here is the code implementation.Any suggestions would help as i am new to this framework.Thanks in advance:)

#

```
import UIKit

import MultipeerConnectivity

var session : MCSession!

var peer : MCPeerID!

var browser : MCNearbyServiceBrowser!

var advertiser : MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!


var foundPeers = [MCPeerID]()

var invitationHandler : ((Bool, MCSession?)->Void)!


class MCPManager: NSObject,MCSessionDelegate
{

    public func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState)
    {
        return
    }

    public func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID)
    {
        return
    }


    public func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID)
    {
        return
    }

    public func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress)
    {
        return
    }

    public func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL, withError error: Error?)
    {
        return
    }

    override init()
    {
        super.init()

        peer = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)

        session = MCSession(peer: peer) // Ambiguous reference to member 'session(_:peer:didChange)' 

        session.delegate = self  //Ambiguous reference to member 'session(_:peer:didChange)' 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Based on the code of your `init()` I'm wondering if you want all those var declarations inside the `MCPManager` class... do you?

Comment: Yup...this init method will be called while creating a session..Can you find any reasons for the error..Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `session` inside `MCPManager` the compiler is trying to resolve some of the `MCSessionDelegate` funcs that you're defining and can't disambiguate because the calls are incomplete. However It seems like you're trying to assign one of those vars defined in the outer scope. I think what you really want is moving all those vars into the definition of your `MCPManager` class, like this:

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

class MCPManager: NSObject, MCSessionDelegate {
    var session : MCSession!
    var peer : MCPeerID!
    var browser : MCNearbyServiceBrowser!
    var advertiser : MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!
    var foundPeers = [MCPeerID]()
    var invitationHandler : ((Bool, MCSession?)->Void)!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        peer = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
        session = MCSession(peer: peer)
        session.delegate = self
    }

    // MCSessionDelegate methods ommited
}
```

This compiles and I hope it's what you want.

Comment: Thank u soo much:)